# In Django QuerySets, is it possible to order by custom SQL?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a QuerySet which I am compositing out of many filter queries. I would like to order it by a custom SQL expression. Specifically, this is the `ORDER BY` section I would like to append to the query:

```
... 
ORDER BY
greatest(`ff_answer`.`update_ts`,
         if(max(`ff_comment`.`create_ts`) is null,
            '2001-01-01 00:00:01',
             max(`ff_comment`.`create_ts`)
           )
 )
```

Is it possible to do this in Django? I am not worried about portability. Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
my_qs = my_qs.order_by_custom_sql('greatest(`ff_answer`.`update_ts`,
             if(max(`ff_comment`.`create_ts`) is null,
                '2001-01-01 00:00:01',
                 max(`ff_comment`.`create_ts`)
               )
     )'
)
```

I am open to one-off hacks. My only requirement is that the result of this is something I can pass into Django's paginator.

Comment: See [QuerySet.extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra).

Comment: I was looking at it, n dit just dawned on my that MySQL allows you to define a column in the select part and use it in the order by. My only problem now is how to inject a `group by` into this query so that my `MAX(...)` part of the select works well.

Comment: At this level, it is not worth trying to bend the ORM any further. Just use [Manager.raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) or a more powerful [ORM](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Comment: The problem is that the QuerySet gets aggregated from a bunch of filters and based on a bunch of conditionals. Doing RAW SQL would be ugly. To add insult to injury, I would like to paginate it. I feel stuck between a rock and a hard place. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: IMHO the Django ORM design has some bad trade-offs between  easy of use and expressiveness. If I'm not mistaken the result of `Manager.raw` will work with the Paginator, but having to resort to raw SQL is ugly indeed.